# how to run an sql statement base on the value of the select tag in PHP

Tags: php, html, sql

Hi I want to filter my searches in the sql based on the requirement the user wants so i used a select tag and depending on the value of the select tag a certain sql statement will be used but its not working as expected can you help me looked what went wrong here:

```
$strFilterByStatus = $_POST['byStatus'];

<select name="byStatus" id="byStatus" onChange="frmAdminWorklist.submit()">
<option value="all">All</option>
<option value="recovered">Recovered</option>
    <option value="unrecovered">Unrecovered</option>
</select>

<?php   
    if($strFilterByStatus=='all'){
       $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM  tblcase";
       $SQL=mysql_query($strSQL);   
    }
?>
```

appreciate the help :)

Comment: You have to submit the form contents through either a submission or AJAX

Comment: How is it `not working as expected`? What is expected vs. how is it currently working?

Comment: You should be using MySQLi as MySQL is deprecated and will be removed in future

Comment: Hi Thank you for your answers

@Sean not working im expecting that when i select all the if condition will be true but it seems like its not getting the value of the select tag

Comment: hi @SyntaxLAMP yeah its now working i used submission tnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose this is all in theTest.php

```
<?php
    $strFilterByStatus = $_POST['byStatus'];
?>

<form id='testform" action="theTest.php" method="post">
  <select name="byStatus" id="byStatus" onChange="frmAdminWorklist.submit()">
    <option value="all">All</option>
    <option value="recovered">Recovered</option>
    <option value="unrecovered">Unrecovered</option>
  </select>
  <input type='submit' name='' value='Go test it'>
</form>

<?php   
    if ( $strFilterByStatus == 'all' )
    {
       $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM  tblcase";
       $SQL = mysql_query($strSQL);   
    }
?>
```

Comment: hi thanks for your answer but yeah it is already inside a form are you suggessting that it will refresh when the form is submitted?